# Can't get information from Redis with Node

Tags: node.js, redis

So, I have this script using the tunnel-ssh and redis npm packages. The thing is I think I have everything done correctly and still can't make it to show some data. It says that the connection is done right with the tunnel and redis.

```
const tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');
const fs = require('fs');
const redis = require('redis');


let config = {
        username: username,
        dstPort: 6379,
        localPort: 6379,
        dstHost: host.myjob.com,
        host: host.myjob.com',
        privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('private_key.pem')
//      passpharse: 'secret',
//      keepAlive: true
};

var server = tunnel(config, function(error,server){
    console.log("SSH connection successfully done.");
    var client = redis.createClient();
    //console.log(client);
    client.select(2, function() {
        client.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('connected');
        });
        client.hgetall('product', function(err, reply) {
            console.log(reply);
        });
    });
});

server.on('error', function(err){
    console.error('Something bad happened:', err);
});
```

The only console message I get is "SSH connection successfully done" and I actually don't know why. Btw this is my first aproach to working with Redis, so I don't really get it.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

please use `async-redis` module
and run this code, its work for me

```
const tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');
const fs = require('fs');
const redis = require("async-redis");
var client = redis.createClient({
    host: "127.0.0.1", //host name
    db: 2, //redis db 
  });

let config = {
        username: username,
        dstPort: 6379,
        localPort: 6379,
        dstHost: host.myjob.com,
        host: host.myjob.com',
        privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('private_key.pem')
//      passpharse: 'secret',
//      keepAlive: true
};

var server = tunnel(config,async function(error,server){
    console.log("SSH connection successfully done.");
    let reply = await client.hgetall("tgju_open_price_13990509")
    console.log(reply)
});

server.on('error', function(err){
    console.error('Something bad happened:', err);
});
```